# I have been asked to either develop or find a videos/photos archiving system

Tags: software-development, video, images, archiving

I have been asked by my college to either develop or find a videos/photos archiving system.

we currently store all our photos and video projects on a shared hard drive over the college network. They are organized by date and some sort of title, but there is no metatagging and they are not easily accessible from off campus.

Should the archive be hosted on the cloud? Should it be developed in house, or is there a commercial product out there that would be preferable? Ideally, I would like to find a platform that would allow me to create a custom dashboard. What I would want to be able to do is make it easy for a student worker with no training to upload files and enter keywords. Then I would like to have some kind of search capability and the ability to view thumbnails that match a search which could be downloaded, preferably over the web.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that this is a *software recommendation* site. Questions like "Should it be developed in house?" and "Should the archive be hosted on the cloud?" are **policy decisions** that you have to answer first by talking about them. Then, if you have decided you need software, ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could be talking about [Media Goblin](http://www.mediagoblin.org/).

- Free & Open Source
- Can add custom components
- Tagging
- Commenting on media is available
- Other media types supported, (not just photos).
- Self hosted.
- You can even build an Android App

For an example site see [here](https://wiki.mediagoblin.org/Live_instances) for a list of public sites.
[image]

Comment: @Rami.Shareef it seems thing like tags, searches, gps, etc. is via plugins see https://wiki.mediagoblin.org/Available_Plugins